# Hartley oscillator problem

Tags: oscillator, passive-networks

For a couple of days, I have been trying to build Hartley oscillator on my **breadboard** based on this schematic:

[image: Hartley oscillator schematic]

([Original source of schematic diagram above](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/hartley.html))

Redrawn with components I chose:

[image: hand drawn schematic]

And here is the scope output:

**Yellow signal** - point X of original schematic

**Blue signal** - point Z of original schematic

**Purple signal** - OUTPUT

[image: photo of oscilloscope traces]

Theoretically we have sine wave on the output, and the voltage on the two inductors is 180 degrees out of phase, but I feel like this is not OK. First of all, the amplitude of the output is too small and second, even more important, I expected about 800 Hz no 100 MHz (as you can see on the scope).

So the question is: What is wrong with my circuit?

Comment: Your Blue signal is point Y, which is ground?

Comment: All signals are grounded on circuit ground.

Comment: Point Y (Blue) measured with respect to ground should be a straight line on oscilloscope ( 0 volts ).

Comment: Right, my mistake - blue signal is Z not Y. I apologize for confusion.

Comment: Are you sure about those frequencies? 2.2 mH with 10 uF is not going to give you 3.5 MHZ. Values should be 2.2 uH and 10 nF.

Comment: @Sparky256, yes this is another mistake I did. The frequency shuld be about 800Hz but this not explain the weird output I see right?

Comment: @DannyS - Please edit your question and fix all the mistakes which you are mentioning in comments. You cannot assume that readers will read every comment (and so they might not read all of your corrections).

Comment: @SamGibson, I edited the question. Thanks for good suggestion.

Comment: Your tank has a higher Q at frequencies higher than 800Hz. It really wants to oscillate based on all the parasitics. Those 2mH inductors I bet are lousy when coupled to a 250Ohm base bias load.  The base DC bias has too low of an impedance. The collector load also seems on the low side. This circuit doesn’t need such high stiffness at low frequencies. It’ll work just fine with a 0.1mA of collector current. It’ll have lousy Q at high frequencies but a good one below 1kHz.

Answer (score 3):

Beyond ca 10 MHz, breadboard simply becomes unusable due to high parasitic inductance and capacitive coupling between adjacent rows.

Build your circuit again on a piece of perfboard or better yet double-sided copper clad board with traces cut out on the top side only.

Comment: There is a mistake in my calculation - OUTPUT should be about 800 Hz not 3.5 Mhz. I do agree that breadbard is noisy but I feel like this is not the root of the problem here.

Comment: What if your breadboard *is* one of your problems? Component values aside, Marcus is correct. A breadboard is no place for RF circuits. +1

Comment: Well there are projects on youtube which shows AM and FM transmitters mounted entirely on breadboard so I wouldn't blame it for everything. Although it is a big capacitor and absorbs a lot of energy.

Answer (score 2):

The total inductance is 4.4 milliHenry. The tank capacitor is 10uF. Fresonate is

1/[ 2*pi*sqrt*L*C) ] = 0.159 / sqrt(4.4e-3 * 1e-5) = 0.159/sqrt(4.4e-8)

Fresonate = 0.159/2e-4 = 10,000 * 0.08 = 800Hz.

==============================

Large inductors have lots of parasitic capacitance, such as between layers.

And your "breadboard" will have suspicious inductors, such as 10nH or 20nH, all over the place.

Alter your connections, by tieing the inductor midpoint the other 3 components also tied to GND.

AND ADD A 0.1uF capacitor from this new single-point GND to the VDD pin.

Comment: Correct, I forgot about the square root in denominator. But even so the result I get are incorrect! Do you have the reason for that?

Comment: You seem to show two separate 2.2mH inductances. The inductance should be a single inductor with a tapped winding.

Comment: @henros that is profoundly incorrect.

Comment: @Andy aka Woops! That comes from staying up past my bedtime when the mind is not in gear. Sorry everybody!

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, I don't understand the last two sentences from your post. I have inductors midpoint connected to GND, what other components you want me to ground? Could you please draw the schematic for it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your biasing resistor values - they are much too low and the oscillator isn't er... oscillating. Try resistor bias resistors that are ten times higher so they do not load the coils and capacitors too much. Try making R1 about 5 to 10 kohms and R2 about 2 to 3 kohms.

The 100 MHz you see on your o-scope is very low level I suspect and not related to the oscillator working unless you have component values shown incorrectly in your diagram.

Look at this Colpitts oscillator design (very similar to the Hartley) and note the values of the bias resistors: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/704813410405492864/).

Also, why not try simulating it?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I think base biasing is good advice although it didn't help. Even worst, I tried to assembly colpitts circuit and got the same output which I think is just noise. Simulation is good advice too, I will check it too.

Comment: Did you get this circuit working @DannyS ?

Comment: I tried colpitts using this schematic https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/NPN_Colpitts_oscillator_collector_coil.svg and eventually got it working. However I made some changes since thse circuit wasn't working as expected. Can I post extended story somwehere here?